# Meaning of "court" in "court languages of Latin and French"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *court* as used in *as did the court languages of Latin and French*?

Comment: The rusted chains of prison moons are shattered by the sun...

Answer (score 6):

*The court* means the monarch's close circle: family, friends and advisers. In the words of the Oxford English Dictionary, it is *The establishment and surroundings of a sovereign with his councillors and retinue.*

Answer (score 6):

It mean the language used in the king's court: presumably this is a reference to the kings of England, where the religious courtiers would often use Latin and the secular Norman courtiers would use French.

The peasants went on using Anglo-Saxon which evolved into English but that really only entered the court when the king was in dispute with his French cousins.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with religion: Latin was simply the elite language, the language of science and other technical literature. It would have been used at court by the non-religious too. The association of Latin with religion is relatively recent (only a few centuries).

Comment: ‘The island at present . . . contains five nations, the English, Britons, Scots, Picts, and Latins, each in its own peculiar dialect cultivating the sublime study of Divine truth. The Latin tongue is, by the study of the Scriptures, become common to all the rest.

(Bede, ‘Ecclesiatical History of the English Nations’, c. 730)